# Borland C++ builder 6 linker error

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6

I am recompling a project using Borland C++ Builder 6. The recompile process failed due to linker error. The message was:

"[Linker Fatal error] Fatal unable to open file ABCC.lib"

I removed all references of ABCC.lib in the project option and environment options, but the same error still occurred. I even tried manually removed ABCC.lib from the .bpr file, but the error just did not go away.

Also, what is the ABCC.lib?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

David.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking for #pragma link or #pragma comment lines in your headers/source code that may be asking for this library?